# Is there an easier way of getting elements by ID in my Polymer Element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a PolymerElement in which I frequently need to access internal elements by ID. My polymer element looks like this:

```html
<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
  <div id="idOne">...</div>
  <div id="idTwo">...</div>
  ....
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Currently accessing the various divs looks like this:

```dart
// other stuff here.
var elOne = shadowRoot.querySelector('#idOne');
var elTwo = shadowRoot.querySelector('#idTwo');
```

Is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely! The Polymer class provides a Shadow root accessor to query elements by ID from within your custom element. Simply use [`$[]`](http://api.dartlang.org/polymer/Polymer.html#%24).

The above dart code becomes:

```dart
var elOne = $['idOne'];
var elTwo = $['idTwo'];
```

Note, it's important that you leave out the hash symbol (`#`) from the ID. Currently this form only supports querying the Shadow Root by ID, and that class-based selection and [ElementLists](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/ElementList.html) are not currently supported.